# Angular2: How to get the content of page into string using Angular 2 service

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple Angular2 service, looks something like this:

```
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

const BASE_URL = 'http://www.example.com/read-this-page.php';

@Injectable()
export class GetPageService {

  constructor(private _http: Http) {
  }

  search(query) {
    return this._http.get(`${BASE_URL}?v=${query}`);
  }

}
```

Then inside my app component I have a click event:

```
click2GetPageContent(event: any) {

 this.results = this.GetPageService.search(value).toString();
   console.log(this.results);
  }
```

Why doesn't this work?
I am getting: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined

Comment: "Cannot read property 'search' of undefined" implies the member this.GetPageService is undefined. Have you injected the service into the app component and assigned it to that member ?

Comment: I've added the service to providers, then inside the app component, created a public GetPageService: GetPageService. That should work now?

Comment: You need to have it as a constructor parameter for it to be injected, is that the case? Can you paste the code for the constructor?

Comment: I did that and now I get Observable {_isScalar: false} when I try to console.log the output in the service and response:[object Object] when I try to console.log output of the service from inside the click event

Comment: I've resolved getting: Observable {_isScalar: false} error, by doing this inside the service:   this.response = this._http.get(this.url).map(res => res.toString());  console.log("Output"+ this.response); but now I am getting: Output[object Object] in console. Why is it not reading the url?

Comment: The Http.get method returns an observable, not plain text. You probably need to review the docs on the Http service. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html - basically you need to subscribe to this observable (it's like a promise, but not exactly the same).

Comment: Actually I see you resolved that. The next issue then is res is not plain text, it's the response object. Just using toString() will convert the object to a string representation which is always [object Object]. See "Process the response object" in the docs linked in my previous comment.

Comment: Hi James, I am not sure I get it. If I do this.response = this._http.get(this.theUrl).map(res => res.toString()); it doesn't work. this.response = this._http.get(this.theUrl).map(res => res.text()); doesn't work either, nor does this.response = this._http.get(this.theUrl).toString();

Comment: this.GetPageService.search(value).subscribe(data => console.log(data)); Do that in your component

Comment: @Kyrsberg, thank you so much. That resolved it. This is how I went about executing it: this.GetPageService.search(value)
        .map(res => res.text())
        .subscribe(
          data => this.results = data,
          err => this.err(err),
          () => console.log("Download Complete!")
        );